# How to vertically align text to scale with website background that is scaled by computer resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a fixed background made to cover the screen and not scale when zoomed using this code:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url('https://i.gyazo.com/81f57cfd79c0b411b6dcd94511df169a.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -83vh;
  width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  color: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <h2>Heading 2</h2>
  <div class="button">
    <a href="#">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

All of this works fine. But there is a bench in my picture that I would like the 2 headings to rest on. [Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoWOk.jpg)

This makes it align properly, but only for my computer and my resolution. Here is an example of some [other resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBJWL.jpg)

Also, I am really bad with javascript, so if that is the only way to fix this issue, please use as much detail as possible in your answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/j8qeeogL/), I've changed the `.container` positioning `bottom`to `top`, and instead of making it fully relying on the `vh` value I've made some kind of balance - *using css function `calc()`* -to make it depends on the `vw` as well since the difference between screen sizes are mostly depending on width.

so instead of this:

```
bottom: -83vh;
```

I changed it to this:

```
top: calc(20vh + 9vw);
```

** *NOTE THAT* you might need to fine-tune the above `vh` and `vw` values to get the best result, i.e the above values suits the result view of **jsfiddle*, for a real screen example this fits more:

```
top: calc(30vh + 8vw);
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

The below relatively complicated, solution uses JavaScript as well as CSS `top` position also "*responsive font sizing*", I've made different tests for desktop/laptop tested with *Chrome46* , *Safari5.1* , *IE7-11* and *Firefox42.0* and , *Opera12*, everything works fine except for IE8 and below because of the lack of supporting new CSS rules, also on opera12 text looked below the bench this version is very old but I keep because I need one of its features, I commented  conditional lines for opera if you want to test the new version of it.

Using [Chrome Device Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/) 
[image: Chrome Device Mode]

this code was tested on all devices - *portrait and landscape* - and it is working fine (*except on iPhone4 portrait it's shifted down a little, Nexus10 landscape a shifted little up and on BlackBerry PlayBook shifted up.

**Full Code:** - *wouldn't work very well on jsfiddle, codepen and other online editors* because of the difference in height.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            body {
                padding: 0;
                background-image: url('http://saltysdesigns.com/ConstructionBackground.jpg');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .container {
                position: absolute;
                top: calc(43vh + 4vw);
                width: 100%;
            }
            h1 {
                font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 700;
                color: #f9f9f9;
                text-align: center;
                opacity: 0.8;
                padding: 0;
            }
            h2 {
                font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 200;
                color: #f9f9f9;
                text-align: center;
                opacity: 0.8;
                margin-top: -1.5vh;
            }
            .button {
                margin-top: 100px;
                text-align: center;
                padding-bottom: 100px;
            }
            .button a {
                background-color: transparent;
                color: #f9f9f9;
                font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-size: 16pt;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
                border-radius: 8px;
                border: 2px #f9f9f9 solid;
                -webkit-transition:background-color 200ms ease-in, border 200ms ease-in, color 200ms ease-in;
                -moz-transition:background-color 200ms ease-in, border 200ms ease-in, color 200ms ease-in;
                -o-transition:background-color 200ms ease-in, border 200ms ease-in, color 200ms ease-in;
                transition:background-color 200ms ease-in, border 200ms ease-in, color 200ms ease-in;
            }
            .button a:hover {
                background-color: #26be8a;
                border: 2px #38d8a1 solid;
                color: #101010;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>COMING SOON</h1>
            <h2>Salty's Designs, Freelance Website &amp; Graphic Design</h2>
            <div class="button">
                <a href="mailto:mail@saltysdesigns.com">Contact Me</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Declaring variables
            var $shifting, $font, $winW, $winH, $winRatio, $varHeight, $UA, $matchFF, $browser, $mode,
                $win = $(window),
                $cont = $('.container'),
                $btn = $('.button'),

                // Below the background image width and height in pixels...
                // if you use another background image make sure to change -
                // these values to the new image width and height values.
                $imgW = 2079,
                $imgH = 1562,
                $imgRatio = ($imgW / $imgH).toFixed(3),

                // Detecting browsers
                $UA = navigator.userAgent;
            if ($UA.match(/firefox/i)) {
                $browser = 'Firefox';
            } else if ($UA.indexOf('Trident') != -1 && $UA.indexOf('MSIE') == -1) {
                $browser = 'MSIE';
            } else if ($UA.indexOf('MSIE') != -1) {
                $browser = 'MSIE';
            } else if ($UA.indexOf('OPR/') != -1) {
                $browser = 'Opera';
            } else if ($UA.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
                $browser = 'Chrome';
            } else if ($UA.indexOf("Safari")!=-1) {
                $browser = 'Safari';
            }
            if($UA.match(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Nokia|Mobile|Opera Mini/i)) {
                $browser = 'Mobile';
            }else if($UA.match(/KFAPWI/i)){
                $browser = 'Kindle';
            }
            if($UA.match(/Nexus/i)){
                $browser = 'Nexus';
            }

            // Calling the adjust() function to initialize calculations -
            // first time page loads.
            adjust();

            $win.resize(function(){
                // Calling the adjust() function on window resizing.
                adjust();    
            });

            function adjust(){
                // Grabbing the view width and height on resize event...
                // Then calculate the view ratio to compare it to the-
                // background image ratio.
                $winW = $win.width();
                $winH = $win.height();
                $winRatio = ($winW / $winH).toFixed(3);

                if($winRatio < $imgRatio){ 
                    // Static image height, only image width changes while resizing
                    $varHeight = 'static';  
                }else{
                    // Image height changes while resizing
                    $varHeight = 'dynamic'; 
                }

                // Below calculating the value of needed down shifting -
                // for different browsers, with comparison for H2 text -
                // break-points when it become 2 lines.
                if ($varHeight == 'static'){
                    switch($browser){
                        case 'Firefox':
                            $shifting = 0.23 * $winH;
                            if($winW < 471){
                                $btn.css({'margin-top':'77px'});    
                            }else{
                                $btn.css({'margin-top':'100px'});
                            }
                            break;

                        case 'Chrome':
                            $shifting = 0.25 * $winH;
                            if($winW < 493){
                                $btn.css({'margin-top':'77px'});    
                            }else{
                                $btn.css({'margin-top':'100px'});
                            }
                            break;

                        case 'MSIE':
                            $shifting = 0.25 * $winH;
                            if($winW < 488){
                                $btn.css({'margin-top':'75px'});    
                            }else{
                                $btn.css({'margin-top':'98px'});
                            }
                            break;

                        case 'Safari':
                            $shifting = 0.235 * $winH;
                            if($winW < 487){
                                $btn.css({'margin-top':'70px'});    
                            }else{
                                $btn.css({'margin-top':'94px'});
                            }
                            break;

                        case 'Mobile':
                            $shifting = 0.345 * $winH;
                            break;

                        case 'Kindle':
                            $shifting = 0.375 * $winH;
                            break;

                        case 'Nexus':
                            $shifting = 0.338 * $winH;
                            break;

                        //case 'Opera':
                        //  break;

                        default:
                            $shifting = 0.25 * $winH;
                    }


                    $font = 0.03 * $winH; // similar to css 3vh;
                }
                else{
                    switch($browser){
                        case 'Firefox':
                            $shifting = 0.178 * $winH - 0.015 * $winW;
                            break;

                        case 'Safari':
                            $shifting = 0.172 * $winH - 0.015 * $winW;
                            break;

                        case 'Mobile':
                            $shifting = 0.175 * $winH;
                            $btn.css({'margin-top':'70px'});
                            if($UA.match(/iPad/i)){
                                $shifting = 0.2 * $winH;
                                $btn.css({'margin-top':'100px'});
                            }
                            break;

                        case 'Nexus':
                            $shifting = 0.17 * $winH;
                            $btn.css({'margin-top':'70px'});
                            break;

                        case 'Kindle':
                            $shifting = 0.3 * $winH;
                            break;

                        //case 'Opera':
                        //  break;

                        default:
                            $shifting = 0.196 * $winH - 0.015 * $winW;
                    }

                    $font = 0.02 * $winW + 0.015 * $winH;   
                }

                // Finally applying the down shifting value to the CSS -
                // of the container, and font size values for the <h>'s.
                $cont.css({ 'top':$shifting});
                $cont.children('h1').css({'font-size': 2 * $font});
                $cont.children('h2').css({'font-size': $font});
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For the most part that worked. Not sure if my math is just wrong, but it doesn't look like a 100% solution. Also, I changed the font sizes to scale with vw and that helped a lot too.

Comment: I believe it is not a fix, it's just a work around and it doesn't make the one 100% satisfied, but it's the easiest way.. Another more complicated solution is with javascript and multi `if .. else if` statements like thresholds  to readjust the `top` value for every let's say `200px` but again it won't be 100% reliable because measuring with `vh` and `vw` can vary depending on screen sizes

Comment: With this, will it work with tablets, and phones as well? Or should I just keep my @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) tag? It gets really funky when the device is taller than it is wide.

Comment: it does work on phone, in the answer I wrote I've tested it with 4 or 5 devices emulators , nexus 4 and nexus10, galaxy s3, s4 and tab3, iphone 6 and 6 plus,  each with landscape and portrait as well as desktop browsers and it works well on all of these

Comment: If it is wrapped in a table, if the `td` - *which contain this background image and text* - if this `td` is full width then it will work just fine, if not full width like 50% or `30` then it wouldn't, because all the calculations depends on the full width

Comment: Here is my full code. I still can't seem to get it right for everything. https://jsfiddle.net/mpy1p17u/

Comment: Actually it is working well, the problem is your CSS here differs than the posted one, different padding and/or margin values, especially for the `Contact Me` button, it has different values, the image ratio of your background image is different also, give me some time I will adjust it

Comment: also you were NOT including jQuery!, how about this `<!-- <div class="divider" style="height: 1px; background-color: #f9f9f9; opacity: 0.2; width: auto; margin-top: -50px;"></div> -->`, will uncomment it later?

Comment: Ah yeah. I took that out and just left it there in case I wanted to keep it for later. Forgot about it. It is meaningless though.